# How to clear interrupt with perpiheral handle? Embedded Rust

Tags: rust, embedded, stm32, interrupt

Few weeks ago I started to learn Rust Embedded.
Now I'm stuck, and I would like to ask you for help. So..

I wanted to use TIM3 in my code to change variable (in future peripheral state) and clear (unpend?) interrupt via registers inside ISR.

In C I did something like this inside ISR:

```c
void TIM3_IRQHandler(void)
{
  if (TIM3->SR & TIM_SR_UIF)
  {
    TIM3->SR &= ~(TIM_SR_UIF);
  }
}
```

..and now I'm stuck to do this in Rust.
At first I show what I've done so far.

```
#![no_std]
#![no_main]

use panic_halt as _;

use cortex_m_rt::entry;

use core::{cell::RefCell};
use core::ops::DerefMut;
use cortex_m::interrupt::{self, Mutex};
use stm32g0::stm32g071::{self, Interrupt, NVIC, TIM3};

static G_TIM: Mutex<RefCell<Option<stm32g071::TIM3>>> =
    Mutex::new(RefCell::new(None));

#[entry]
fn main() -> ! {
    let p = stm32g071::Peripherals::take().unwrap();

    let rcc_r = &p.RCC;

    let timer_r = &p.TIM3;

    let tim3 = p.TIM3;

    unsafe {
        NVIC::unmask(Interrupt::TIM3);
    };

    rcc_r.apbenr1.write(|w| w.tim3en().set_bit());

    prepare_timer3(timer_r);

    interrupt::free(|cs| {
        G_TIM.borrow(cs).replace(Some(tim3))
    });

    loop {
    }
}

fn prepare_timer3(tim3_r_handle: &TIM3) {
    tim3_r_handle.cr1.write(|w| w.cen().clear_bit());
    tim3_r_handle.psc.write(|w| unsafe { w.psc().bits(16000) });
    tim3_r_handle.arr.write(|w| unsafe { w.arr_l().bits(100) });
    tim3_r_handle.egr.write(|w| w.ug().set_bit());
    tim3_r_handle.dier.write(|w| w.uie().set_bit());
    tim3_r_handle.cr1.write(|w| w.cen().set_bit());
}

#[interrupt]
fn TIM3() {
    interrupt::free(|cs| {
        if let Some(ref mut tim3) =  G_TIM.borrow(cs).borrow_mut().deref_mut() {
            tim3.sr.write(|w| w.uif().clear_bit());
        }
    })
}
```

And I get this compilation error:

```
error: cannot find attribute `interrupt` in this scope
  --> src/main.rs:51:3
   |
51 | #[interrupt]
   |   ^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: consider importing one of these items:
           cortex_m_rt::interrupt
           crate::stm32g071::interrupt
           stm32g0::stm32g071::interrupt
note: `interrupt` is imported here, but it is a module, not an attribute
  --> src/main.rs:10:27
   |
10 | use cortex_m::interrupt::{self, Mutex};
   |                           ^^^^

error: could not compile `blink-nucleo-g0` due to previous error
```

I have problem how to resolve those dependency problem.
Could you tell me also that what I did with this Mutex G_TIM is fine?
I mean I did this after read this article: https://docs.rust-embedded.org/book/concurrency/#sharing-peripherals
I also read this https://users.rust-lang.org/t/rust-embedded-stm32f303-timer-interrupt-hanging/40323 but I don't want to use hal crates.

I asked at Rust forum too: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-clear-interrupt-with-perpiheral-handle/67214

EDIT:
I changed to:

```
use cortex_m::interrupt::free;
use cortex_m::interrupt::Mutex;
use stm32g0::stm32g071::{self, Interrupt, NVIC, TIM3, interrupt};
```

and usage of interrupt::free to free.

```
#[interrupt]
fn TIM2() {
    free(|cs| {
        if let Some(ref mut tim2) = G_TIM.borrow(cs).borrow_mut().deref_mut() {
            tim2.sr.write(|w| w.uif().clear_bit());
        }
    });
}
```

I think that my ISR is invkoing in loop. How to clear this interrupt properly?

EDIT:
I changed whole to TIM2.
I cannot reach line `tim2.sr.write(|w| w.uif().clear_bit());` with debugger. I think above `if let` returns false, why?

Comment: I suggest you create an issue in https://github.com/rust-embedded/book

Comment: Ok, I created an issue at: https://github.com/rust-embedded/book/issues/307

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed instructions in GitHub issue and it worked. I wasn't using `Mutex` and `interrupt::free` properly. `if let..` in ISR was returning false because interrupt was exectued before replace so... it has value of `None` in interrupt.

This is my code that works, after fix.

```
#![no_std]
#![no_main]

use panic_halt as _;

use core::cell::RefCell;
use core::ops::DerefMut;
use cortex_m::interrupt::free;
use cortex_m::interrupt::Mutex;
use cortex_m_rt::entry;
use stm32g0::stm32g071::{self, interrupt, Interrupt, NVIC};

static G_TIM: Mutex<RefCell<Option<stm32g071::TIM2>>> = Mutex::new(RefCell::new(None));
static G_GPIOA: Mutex<RefCell<Option<stm32g071::GPIOA>>> = Mutex::new(RefCell::new(None));

#[entry]
fn main() -> ! {
    let p = stm32g071::Peripherals::take().unwrap();

    let gpioa = &p.GPIOA;
    let rcc_r = &p.RCC;

    // enable Clock for GPIOA
    rcc_r.iopenr.modify(|_, w| w.iopaen().set_bit());

    let tim2 = p.TIM2;

    // Nucleo G071RB LED so need to set as output
    gpioa.moder.modify(|_, w| unsafe { w.moder5().bits(0b01) });

    rcc_r.apbenr1.write(|w| w.tim2en().set_bit());
    free(|cs| {
        tim2.cr1.write(|w| w.cen().clear_bit());
        tim2.psc.write(|w| unsafe { w.psc().bits(16000) });
        tim2.arr.write(|w| unsafe { w.arr_l().bits(1000) });
        tim2.egr.write(|w| w.ug().set_bit());
        tim2.dier.write(|w| w.uie().set_bit());
        tim2.cr1.write(|w| w.cen().set_bit());
        G_TIM.borrow(cs).replace(Some(tim2));
    });

    // NVIC unmask interrupt
    unsafe {
        NVIC::unmask(Interrupt::TIM2);
    };

    let gpioa = p.GPIOA;
    free(|cs| {
        G_GPIOA.borrow(cs).replace(Some(gpioa));
    });

    let mut increment = 0;
    loop {
        increment += 1;
        if increment > 1000 {
            increment = 0;
        }
    }
}

#[interrupt]
fn TIM2() {
    free(|cs| {
        if let Some(ref mut tim2) = G_TIM.borrow(cs).borrow_mut().deref_mut() {
            tim2.sr.write(|w| w.uif().clear_bit());
        }
    });

    free(|cs| {
        if let Some(ref mut gpioa) = G_GPIOA.borrow(cs).borrow_mut().deref_mut() {
            if gpioa.odr.read().odr5().bit_is_set() {
                gpioa.odr.modify(|_, w| w.odr5().clear_bit());
            } else {
                gpioa.odr.modify(|_, w| w.odr5().set_bit());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The macro attribute [`#[interrupt]`](https://docs.rs/cortex-m-rt/0.7.0/cortex_m_rt/attr.interrupt.html) is exposed in `cortex-m-rt` not `cortex-m` as book chapter [`Interrupts`](https://docs.rust-embedded.org/book/start/interrupts.html) document:

> Similarly to exceptions, the cortex-m-rt crate provides an interrupt attribute to declare interrupt handlers.

Comment: If I add ```use cortex_m_rt::interrupt;``` I've got problem with TIM3 function. Even if I have ```use stm32g0::stm32g071::{..., TIM3}``` line.